# Should I use OAuth2 Implicit flow for client side app?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth

I'm learning OAuth2 by writing a simple client-side React app. Currently, I don't know which of these 2 flows to choose:

- Implicit flow: Suggested by Google OAuth (my test code use their OAuth service)
- Authorization code with PKCE: [Suggested](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#authorization) by Aaron Parecki. He explicitly mentioned that it replaces the Implicit flow as best practice.

So which one should I choose?

Update: My app also has server part, not just a client. Think of a Todo app, and users can use Google to login to see their stuffs which is saved on my server. I add this because I think Implicit flow could be for purely client side app (however I can't think of any such app).

Comment: It is not recommended to use the implicit flow (and some servers prohibit this flow entirely) due to the inherent risks of returning access tokens in an HTTP redirect without any confirmation that it has been received by the client. [Source](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/)

Comment: I'll close this one. The thing I should use is OIDC, just found  out about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code flow with PKCE. It's much more secure than the implicit flow. The implicit flow will be removed from OAuth in the OAuth 2.1 specification, so it will become deprecated soon.

It doesn't matter if you use pure OAuth or OIDC, they both use the same flows. So even if you need OIDC, go with the code flow.